# Large amount of memory allocated by net/protocol.rb:153

Tags: ruby

While running `memory_profiler`, I noticed a large amount of memory being allocated by Ruby's net/protocol.rb component. I call it when performing an HTTP request to a server to download a file. The file is 43.67MB large and net/protocol.rb alone allocates 262,011,476 bytes just to download it.

Looking at the "allocated memory by location" section in the profiler report below, I can see `net/protocol.rb:172` and `http/response.rb:334` allocating 50-60MB of memory each, which is about the size of the file, so that looks reasonable. However, the top most entry (`net/protocol.rb:153`) worries me: that's 200MB of memory, at least 4x the size of the file.

I have two questions:

1. Why does net/protocol need to allocate 5x the size of the file in order to download it?
2. Is there anything I can do to reduce the amount of memory used by net/protocol?

`memory_profiler` output:

```
Total allocated: 314461424 bytes (82260 objects)
Total retained:  0 bytes (0 objects)

allocated memory by gem
-----------------------------------
 314461304  ruby-2.1.2/lib
       120  client/lib

allocated memory by file
-----------------------------------
 262011476  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb
  52435727  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb
      7971  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb
      2178  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb
      1663  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb
      1260  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb
       949  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/generic.rb
       120  /Users/andre.debrito/git/techserv-cache/client/lib/connections/cache_server_connection.rb
        80  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/http.rb

allocated memory by location
-----------------------------------
 200483909  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:153
  60548199  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:172
  52428839  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:334
    978800  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:155
      2537  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:61
      2365  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:172
      2190  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:54
      1280  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:56
       960  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:62
       836  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:165
       792  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:13
       738  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:125
       698  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:263
       576  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:214
       489  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:40
       480  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:127
       360  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:40
       328  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:610
       320  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:71
       320  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:30
       320  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:59
       308  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:322
       256  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879
       240  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/generic.rb:1615
       239  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:211
       232  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:38
       224  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:181
       200  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:17
       192  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:42
       179  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:877
       169  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1459
       160  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1029
       160  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:434
       160  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:435
       160  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:445
       160  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/generic.rb:1617
       149  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/generic.rb:1445
       147  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1529
       129  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:98
       128  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1475
       120  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:444
       120  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:446
       120  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:447
       120  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:29
       120  /Users/andre.debrito/git/techserv-cache/client/lib/connections/cache_server_connection.rb:45
        96  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:899
        80  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:39
        80  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:45
        80  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:46
        80  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:145

allocated memory by class
-----------------------------------
 309678360  String
   3445304  Thread::Backtrace
    981096  Array
    352376  IO::EAGAINWaitReadable
      1960  MatchData
      1024  Hash
       328  Net::HTTP
       256  TCPSocket
       256  URI::HTTP
       128  Time
       120  Net::HTTP::Get
       120  Net::HTTPOK
        96  Net::BufferedIO

allocated objects by gem
-----------------------------------
     82259  ruby-2.1.2/lib
         1  client/lib

allocated objects by file
-----------------------------------
     81908  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb
       129  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb
       127  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb
        28  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb
        23  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb
        23  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/generic.rb
        19  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/http.rb
         1  /Users/andre.debrito/git/techserv-cache/client/lib/connections/cache_server_connection.rb

allocated objects by location
-----------------------------------
     36373  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:153
     24470  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:155
     21057  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:172
        48  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:61
        38  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:54
        32  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:56
        31  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:172
        24  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:62
        12  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:127
         9  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:40
         8  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:71
         8  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:165
         8  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:30
         8  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:59
         6  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:214
         6  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/generic.rb:1615
         5  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:263
         4  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1029
         4  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:322
         4  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:17
         4  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:434
         4  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:435
         4  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:445
         4  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:42
         4  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:125
         4  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/generic.rb:1617
         3  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1529
         3  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:444
         3  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:446
         3  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:447
         3  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:40
         3  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/generic.rb:1445
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:877
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:39
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:45
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:46
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:13
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:145
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/header.rb:31
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:111
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:144
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:98
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:179
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:181
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:213
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/generic.rb:1640
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/generic.rb:1642
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/generic.rb:343
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/generic.rb:530
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/generic.rb:557

allocated objects by class
-----------------------------------
     47935  String
     24519  Array
      4894  IO::EAGAINWaitReadable
      4894  Thread::Backtrace
         7  MatchData
         3  Hash
         2  URI::HTTP
         1  Net::BufferedIO
         1  Net::HTTP
         1  Net::HTTP::Get
         1  Net::HTTPOK
         1  TCPSocket
         1  Time

retained memory by gem
-----------------------------------
NO DATA

retained memory by file
-----------------------------------
NO DATA

retained memory by location
-----------------------------------
NO DATA

retained memory by class
-----------------------------------
NO DATA

retained objects by gem
-----------------------------------
NO DATA

retained objects by file
-----------------------------------
NO DATA

retained objects by location
-----------------------------------
NO DATA

retained objects by class
-----------------------------------
NO DATA


Allocated String Report
-----------------------------------
     11926  ""
      7019  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:172
      4894  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:153
        10  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:54
         2  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:179
         1  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:67

      4894  "Resource temporarily unavailable - read would block"
      4894  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:153

      4894  "UTF-8"
      4894  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:153

      4894  "read would block"
      4894  /Users/andre.debrito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:153
...
```

Relevant code:

```
  report = MemoryProfiler.report do
    begin
      response = nil
      Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port).start { |http|
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
        response = http.request request
      }
    rescue Net::ReadTimeout => e
      raise RequestTimeoutError.new(e.message)
    rescue Exception => e
      raise ServerConnectionError.new(e.message)
    end
  end
  report.pretty_print
```

Network traffic data from Charles proxy:

- Request Header: 168 bytes
- Response Header: 288 bytes
- Request: -
- Response: 43.67 MB (45792735 bytes)
- Total: 43.67 MB (45793191 bytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all of those strings allocated in [net/protocol.rb#L153](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_0/lib/net/protocol.rb#L153) are short-lived and are reclaimed by the next GC run. Those allocated objects are thus pretty harmless and will not result in a significantly larger process size.

You get a lot of exceptions (which are used for control flow here to read form the socket) and the actual read data which is appended to the buffer. All of these operations create temporary (internally used) objects.

As such, you are probably measuring the wrong thing. What would probably make more sense is to:

- measure the maximum RSS of the process (i.e. the "used" memory);
- and to measure the amount of additional memory still allocated after the read.

You will notice that (depending on the memory pressure on your computer), the RSS will not grow significantly above the amount of actually read data and that the references memory after the read is about the same size as the read data with about no internal intermediate objects still referenced.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are correct: measuring the memory in use after that piece of code runs, I see it sitting steadily at 77.5MB, so all that memory allocated by net/protocol does get GC'd pretty quick.